# NSMutablearray doesn't prints all array elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'm using the following piece of code to store elements in array dynamically and retrieve it later

```
for (int i = 0; i< [companyNames count]; i++){
    testimonialsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    testimonialsComplementedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [testimonialsArray addObject:companyNames[i] ];
    [testimonialsComplementedArray addObject:texts[i]];

    NSLog(@"Compliments %@",testimonialsComplementedArray);
}
```

But it prints only the last copy that had been added to the array. How to retrieve all elements?

Following are the company names,

```
"General Marketing Company",
 "United Enterprises, Chennai",
 "Hari Match Industries"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

allocate the   `testimonialsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];` in above the for loop if you initilize in inside the loop every time the memory will be initilize, so final value only you get on output in finally , do like

```
testimonialsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
testimonialsComplementedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]
 for (int i = 0; i< [companyNames count]; i++){
  [testimonialsArray addObject:companyNames[i] ];
[testimonialsComplementedArray addObject:texts[i]];
 }

NSLog(@"Compliments %@",testimonialsComplementedArray);
```

Comment: it displays the same testimonials details three times on the screen

Comment: it display the details based on your `companyNames` count bro, you need apart from any thing else

Comment: I think you forget to allocate the memory of `testimonialsComplementedArray` , check the updated answer bro

Comment: I think this one no need in here , ` [testimonialsArray addObject:companyNames[i] ];` in this place you can diectly use testimonialsArray  = companyNames;

Comment: i have allocated the memory. it prints the company details thrice uniquely. But on the ui, same detail is printed thrice.

Comment: then check your `companyNames` datas contains what , can you updte your question bro once

Comment: it displays the same company name three times in the screen.

Comment: we are seen in three different types

Comment: instead of displaying the names of three companies, it displays the same company name three times on the screen

Comment: everything was working fine. Its just that i was displaying the details in wrong textlabel. After fixing it, it worked like a charm..

Comment: Congratz bro happy to hear

Answer (score 0):

```
testimonialsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; // have to init out side the loop
testimonialsComplementedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; // have to init out side the loop
for (int i = 0; i< [companyNames count]; i++){
    [testimonialsArray addObject:companyNames[i] ];
    [testimonialsComplementedArray addObject:texts[i]];        
}
NSLog(@"Compliments %@",testimonialsComplementedArray);
```

Comment: It has to display the testimonial details, compliments in the ui.

Comment: nslog prints unique details but on the ui, it prints the same detail thrice

Comment: It means the problem in the UI code. Please post more code

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating mutable array every time in for loop because of that its initializes array and add object in that everytime.Always its better to alloc any object in ViewDidLoad method.

Comment: is it possible to add the objects outside the loop?

Comment: For every index's object you must add in for loop.

Comment: will you please elaborate?

Comment: As you are using for loop for array named "companyNames",there are number of objects in that array,you want to add every object in another array of Mutable type which need to alloc memory to be used,the int i variable used in for loop is a local variable whose existence is only in that for loop block, as control reaches out of that block the int i variable deallocated means no further available.Thats why its needed to use in for loop to add object in array from another array for every incremented index or value of variable i.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
testimonialsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
testimonialsComplementedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i = 0; i< [companyNames count]; i++){
[testimonialsArray addObject:companyNames[i] ];
[testimonialsComplementedArray addObject:texts[i]];

}
NSLog(@"Compliments %@",testimonialsComplementedArray);
```

Comment: on the ui , same detail is printed thrice

Comment: can u tell me what are the data is there in the companyNames,texts arrays

Comment: Please check Number of sections You given for table view

Comment: ya it displays the same company name three times in the screen

Comment: See,Problem is Some where check your code step by step.No problem is there in i given code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103837/discussion-between-mahesh-reddy-and-stanly).

Comment: ya im trying to display the company details inside the loop. is there anyways which I can do that outside the loop?